# Why isnt Tom Hanks returned in this cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When running this from the Neo4j movie intro

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors) RETURN coActors.name
```

I was expecting to get "Tom Hanks" back since he also matches the "right side" of the match clause.

How come a node matched on left side not matches on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships that are matched multiple times in a single pattern will not be included. 
`(tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)` on the left matches the `ACTED_IN` relationship from Tom Hanks to the movie. This relationship will not be matched again on the right hand side.

Some more examples of this in the Neo4j Manual- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html