# Returning 'co-actors' in the Neo4j cypher tutorial

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am going over the basic tutorial that is bundled with the basic Neo4j installation.

This Cypher query works fine and returns all of Tom Hanks' co-actors.

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors) RETURN coActors.name
```

So the first part of the query returns the node 'Tom Hanks'. No problem. But the part I don't understand is the second part.

The line `<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors) RETURN coActors.name` in no clear way works to exclude 'Tom Hanks' from the result set (although it obviously does). It appears upon reading to return everyone with the relationship `[:ACTED_IN]`...which should include Tom Hanks.

How does this query return all other actors *except* Tom Hanks?

Answer (score 1):

A `MATCH` clause filters out all duplicate relationships. That is why your query does not return "Tom Hanks".

On the other hand, if you split that `MATCH` clause so that the relationships are found in separate clauses, you would see "Tom Hanks" returned:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors)
RETURN coActors.name;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of implementing MATCH to remove duplicates? As far as I can tell the answer becomes inaccurate -- it's true that Tom Hanks was also an actor that appeared in movies that Tom Hanks was in.

Comment: It is claimed by the neo4j folks that this behavior is usually what is wanted. In any case, it is now too late to change it without breaking a large number of existing queries.

Comment: Well glad I figured it out now instead of later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: More info about the uniqueness of relationships matched in a single pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595738/why-isnt-tom-hanks-returned-in-this-cypher-query

Comment: I didn't realize my question was a duplicate.